# How to change SVG source smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, svg

I'm having this problem that I need to change between SVG images smoothly. I need to get from this:

[image: Normal]

to this:

[image: Hover]

I have tried changing fill but it only changes stroke. Is this possible with JS/jQuery, or any other way?

Thanks.

Comment: A couple of questions. **1.** What do you mean by 'smoothly'? - Do you wish to fade from one to the other? and **2.** Are the white areas surrounded by the border in the first image actually white, or are they transparent?

Comment: @enhzflep I mean smooth effect like .2s in CSS, not just that it changes it without any smooth effect. And they're transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that just with css. No need for any script at all.

This code will do it. Basically, img1.svg is the top image you've shown and img2.svg is the bottom image. When the mouse hovers over the containing div (#crossfade), one of the images (img1) fades from opaque to transparent and the other image (img2) fades from transparent to opaque.

Notes:

- In my test, the first image is entirely transparent, except for the
  stroke. The second image is entirely opaque, except for the area
  outside the 'square'
- I didn't bother to run SVG cleaner or anything else like that, hence
  the many digits after the decimal point. (e.g
  `stroke-width:2.93599999999999990`)

I got the code from here: http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-create-the-perfect-image-crossfade-with-css3-transitions/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#crossfade {
    position:relative;
    width: 93px;
    height: 93px;
}


#crossfade img.top {
    opacity:    1;
}

#crossfade img.bottom {
    opacity:    0;
}

#crossfade img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;    
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#crossfade:hover img.top {
    opacity:0;
}

#crossfade:hover img.bottom {
    opacity:1;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="crossfade">
        <img class="bottom" src="img2.svg" />
        <img class="top" src="img1.svg" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**img1.svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="93"
   height="93"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.0 r9654"
   sodipodi:docname="New document 1">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="3.0844832"
     inkscape:cx="59.926082"
     inkscape:cy="41.920868"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:window-width="959"
     inkscape:window-height="551"
     inkscape:window-x="175"
     inkscape:window-y="79"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,-959.36218)">
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#c0a387;stroke-width:2.03600001;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:10"
       d="m 3.018,1006.4853 c 0.0072,-17.50441 29.990486,-45.52256 44.753693,-45.56985 15.40148,-0.0436 43.957267,28.79451 43.638845,42.85735 0.248854,14.9565 -29.04024,45.4972 -44.753694,45.5698 C 30.38076,1049.5955 3.115676,1020.2529 3.018,1006.4853 z"
       id="rect2996"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />
    <path
       transform="translate(0,959.36218)"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#c0a387;stroke-width:2.03600001;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dashoffset:10"
       d="m 61.197651,45.103561 c 0,2.588321 -2.214189,4.883169 -1.286883,7.142733 3.42091,8.335723 2.077738,8.900812 -5.604833,5.604666 -2.488442,-1.067647 -5.089951,2.139333 -8.027619,2.139333 -8.57918,0 -15.53398,-6.665017 -15.53398,-14.886732 0,-8.221714 6.9548,-14.886731 15.53398,-14.886731 8.579181,0 14.919335,6.665017 14.919335,14.886731 z"
       id="path3767"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="sssssss" />
    <path
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#c0a387;stroke-width:2.936;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:10"
       id="path3770"
       sodipodi:cx="39.521751"
       sodipodi:cy="44.750271"
       sodipodi:rx="1.5366156"
       sodipodi:ry="1.6595448"
       d="m 41.058367,44.750271 a 1.5366156,1.6595448 0 1 1 -3.073231,0 1.5366156,1.6595448 0 1 1 3.073231,0 z"
       transform="translate(0,959.36218)" />
    <path
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#c0a387;stroke-width:2.936;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:10"
       id="path3772"
       sodipodi:cx="46.098469"
       sodipodi:cy="44.873199"
       sodipodi:rx="1.4751509"
       sodipodi:ry="1.6595448"
       d="m 47.57362,44.873199 a 1.4751509,1.6595448 0 1 1 -2.950302,0 1.4751509,1.6595448 0 1 1 2.950302,0 z"
       transform="translate(0,959.36218)" />
    <path
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#c0a387;stroke-width:2.936;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:10"
       id="path3774"
       sodipodi:cx="52.859577"
       sodipodi:cy="44.934666"
       sodipodi:rx="1.3522217"
       sodipodi:ry="1.5980803"
       d="m 54.211799,44.934666 a 1.3522217,1.5980803 0 1 1 -2.704444,0 1.3522217,1.5980803 0 1 1 2.704444,0 z"
       transform="translate(0,959.36218)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**img2.svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="93"
   height="93"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.0 r9654"
   sodipodi:docname="img1.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="3.0844832"
     inkscape:cx="59.926082"
     inkscape:cy="41.920868"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:window-width="959"
     inkscape:window-height="551"
     inkscape:window-x="175"
     inkscape:window-y="79"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,-959.36218)">
    <path
       style="fill:#c0a387;stroke:#c0a387;stroke-width:2.03600001000000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:10;fill-opacity:1"
       d="m 3.018,1006.4853 c 0.0072,-17.50441 29.990486,-45.52256 44.753693,-45.56985 15.40148,-0.0436 43.957267,28.79451 43.638845,42.85735 0.248854,14.9565 -29.04024,45.4972 -44.753694,45.5698 C 30.38076,1049.5955 3.115676,1020.2529 3.018,1006.4853 z"
       id="rect2996"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />
    <path
       transform="translate(0,959.36218)"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.03600001000000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dashoffset:10"
       d="m 61.197651,45.103561 c 0,2.588321 -2.214189,4.883169 -1.286883,7.142733 3.42091,8.335723 2.077738,8.900812 -5.604833,5.604666 -2.488442,-1.067647 -5.089951,2.139333 -8.027619,2.139333 -8.57918,0 -15.53398,-6.665017 -15.53398,-14.886732 0,-8.221714 6.9548,-14.886731 15.53398,-14.886731 8.579181,0 14.919335,6.665017 14.919335,14.886731 z"
       id="path3767"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="sssssss" />
    <path
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.93599999999999990;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:10"
       id="path3770"
       sodipodi:cx="39.521751"
       sodipodi:cy="44.750271"
       sodipodi:rx="1.5366156"
       sodipodi:ry="1.6595448"
       d="m 41.058367,44.750271 a 1.5366156,1.6595448 0 1 1 -3.073231,0 1.5366156,1.6595448 0 1 1 3.073231,0 z"
       transform="translate(0,959.36218)" />
    <path
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.93599999999999990;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:10"
       id="path3772"
       sodipodi:cx="46.098469"
       sodipodi:cy="44.873199"
       sodipodi:rx="1.4751509"
       sodipodi:ry="1.6595448"
       d="m 47.57362,44.873199 a 1.4751509,1.6595448 0 1 1 -2.950302,0 1.4751509,1.6595448 0 1 1 2.950302,0 z"
       transform="translate(0,959.36218)" />
    <path
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.93599999999999990;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:10"
       id="path3774"
       sodipodi:cx="52.859577"
       sodipodi:cy="44.934666"
       sodipodi:rx="1.3522217"
       sodipodi:ry="1.5980803"
       d="m 54.211799,44.934666 a 1.3522217,1.5980803 0 1 1 -2.704444,0 1.3522217,1.5980803 0 1 1 2.704444,0 z"
       transform="translate(0,959.36218)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```